# Printing from TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am using the following unit to display - and print - HTML code via a TWebBrowser which is displayed in a non-modal dialog. In my production program, the following code works under Windows-XP but fails with Windows-7 (the error message is always External exception C015D00F). In order to isolate the problem, I wrote a simple test program which also has a non-modal dialog containing a TWebBrowser; on its own, this test program works correctly with Windows-7, but when I plug the non-modal dialog from the test program into the production program, I get the external exception.

This presumably indicates that there is a problem with the calling program and not the called unit, but I can't see what that problem is. The HTML code is hand crafted but displays correctly.

What could be the problem? The printing code comes from the Embarcadero [site](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26402)

```
unit Test4;

interface
uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
 Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, MSHTML;

type
 THTMLPreview = class(TForm)
  web: TWebBrowser;
  procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  procedure webDocumentComplete(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
                                var URL: OleVariant);
  private
   options: word;
   fn: string;
   procedure DoPrint;
  public
   Constructor Create (const afn, acapt: string; opts: word);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor THTMLPreview.Create (const afn, acapt: string; opts: word);                
begin
 inherited create (nil);
 caption:= acapt;
 fn:= afn;
 options:= opts;
 web.Navigate (fn);
end;

procedure THTMLPreview.webDocumentComplete(Sender: TObject;
                 const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
 DoPrint
end;

procedure THTMLPreview.DoPrint;
var
 HTMLDoc: IHTMLDocument2;
 HTMLWnd: IHTMLWindow2;
 HTMLWindow3: IHTMLWindow3;

begin
 if options and 4 = 4 then
  begin
   HTMLDoc:= web.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
   if HTMLDoc <> nil then
    begin
     HTMLWnd:= HTMLDoc.parentWindow;
     HTMLWindow3:= HTMLWnd as IHTMLWindow3;
     HTMLWindow3.print;
    end
  end
end;

procedure THTMLPreview.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 if options and 1 = 1 then deletefile (fn);
 action:= caFree
end;

end.
```

Using the statement `Web.ControlInterface.ExecWB (OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER,
vaIn, vaOut)` gives the same error.

---

Edit from a few days later:

I tried a completely different approach to the problem. In the HTML code I added a javascript snippet which displays a 'print' button and adds an 'onprint' event. Once again, this works fine on my development machine (XP) but not on my client's machines (Win7), where the program freezes with the announcement External exception C015D00F (same address as previously).

---

After no small amount of googling, I discovered that Exception code C015000F is caused by 
"the activation context being deactivated is not the most recently activated one." What does this mean to a poor Delphi programmer?

Comment: What line triggers the exception? And how do you close the form? manually?

Comment: @Noam, I'm not the down-voter, but you still did not provide enough information. please address my comment.

Comment: @kobik: I thought that I was presenting more than enough information. I also posted a comment which referred to your comment but it seems to have disappeared. I don't know which line in the 'DoPrint' routine triggers the exception, but the ControlInterface line has exactly the same problem. The form would be closed manually but crashes before it can be closed.

Comment: @Noam, Your code looks fine to me. I would however provide `Application` as an owner to the form. and do `web.Navigate` on form show, instead of onCreate.

Comment: @kobik: I did as you suggested but there was no change. I have added simple logging statements after each line in the DoPrint procedure, including a line after HTMLWindow3.print - this line appears in the log. In other words, HTMLWindow3.print calls some library code and the crash occurs within that external code.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, the IHTMLWindow3.print method pops up the default 'sent to printer' system dialog. Do you want this? For an application I once searched for a way to avoid this, and then found this code.

```
var
  r:TRect;
  sh,ph:HDC;
begin
  OleInitialize(nil);
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://'+HtmlFilePath);
  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState<>READYSTATE_COMPLETE do Application.HandleMessage;

  //Printer.PrinterIndex:=//set selected printer here
  Printer.BeginDoc;
  try
    Printer.Canvas.Lock;
    try
      sh:=GetDC(0);
      ph:=Printer.Canvas.Handle;

      //TODO: make rect a bit smaller for a page margin
      //TODO: get page size from printer settings, assume A4 here (210x297mm)
      r.Left:=0;
      r.Top:=0;
      r.Right:=2100 * GetDeviceCaps(sh,LOGPIXELSX) div 254;
      r.Bottom:=2970 * GetDeviceCaps(sh,LOGPIXELSY) div 254;
      WebBrowser1.BoundsRect:=r;

      SetMapMode(ph,MM_ISOTROPIC);
      SetWindowExtEx(ph,r.Right,r.Bottom,nil);
      SetViewportExtEx(ph,r.Right,r.Bottom,nil);
      r.Right:=GetDeviceCaps(ph,HORZRES)-1;
      r.Bottom:=GetDeviceCaps(ph,VERTRES)-1;

      (WebBrowser1.ControlInterface as IViewObject).Draw(
        DVASPECT_CONTENT,
        1,
        nil,nil,0,ph,@r,nil,nil,0);
    finally
      Printer.Canvas.Unlock;
    end;
    Printer.EndDoc;
  except
    Printer.Abort;
    raise;
  end;
```

The SetWindowExtEx and SetViewportExtEx set the scaling correct so you can use the unit "mm" in the HTML/CSS.

Comment: the 'and 1 and 1' bit was a typo -should have been 'options and 1 = 1 then' - corrected.

Comment: The webbrowser contains some text, a table (containing some text) and then some text underneath the table. All the text is UTF-8 encoded as it is in Hebrew. Using the above code, only an empty HTML table appeared in the output; none of the text did.

Comment: This code causes the program to crash the computer with Windows-7. It works ok with XP, but as I noted above, the text is missing. So this is not a viable solution.

Comment: Hebrew? Could this be a printer font issue? Are you using the default font or do you have a specific local TTF/OTF font you know has all the Hebrew characters defined?

Comment: I've never specified a font and I don't think it's relevant. The 'choose printer' dialog does not appear under Windows-7 whereas it does in XP (with the code I am using). I can turn my attention to the font once I know that something is printed. The code which you presented crashes the computer - even worse than just my program crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var
    vIn, vOut: OleVariant;
begin
    WebBrowser_mail.ControlInterface.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT,
                    OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vIn, vOut) ;
```

Comment: I did include a variant of this in my posting - read to the end. I have abandoned the idea of printing from the webbrowser under Windows7 until someone can explain how to avoid the external exception C015D00F.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have problems with WB it has two reasons: a) document is not fully loaded b) WB component is not "fully registered" because it is on hidden form etc.

For a) I use a lot of year this code:

```
var
  CurDispatch: IDispatch;
  DocLoaded: boolean;


procedure TForm3.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  if (pDisp = CurDispatch) then begin
    CurDispatch := nil; {clear the global variable }
    DocLoaded:=true;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  if CurDispatch = nil then
    CurDispatch := pDisp; { save for comparison }
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vIn, vOut: OleVariant;

begin
  DocLoaded:=false;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(EdLink.Text);
  repeat
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  until DocLoaded;

  WebBrowser1.ControlInterface.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vIn, vOut)
end;
```

If still problems exist, try to put this to FormShow - it solves b):

```
WebBrowser1.HandleNeeded;
```

No problems with WB anymore.

Do not forget to set WebBrowser1.Silent:=true to hide JavaScript errors in page.