# How to print or view HTML from a TDBGrid?

Tags: html, delphi, printing, reporting, delphi-xe3

I was, until now, unable to find or create a good component to print the result of a `TDBGrid`, so what I did was to create a couple of `for ... do` and then save the result in a text file and opened right after with Notepad, so the user could print or save from there. Pretty ugly, right?

Now it just came to me that I could use those loops to create HTML code instead, which is more presentable. But how can I use, for example a `TWebBrowser` or something else to show that result instead of the `TDBGrid` approach?

And how can I print this HTML (with or without the `TWebBrowser`, as for example if I still use the `TDBGrid` to show the report and the HTML approach just if the user wants to print it)?

Comment: Why display the HTML when you're already displaying the grid with the same data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manually Writing the HTML in TWebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784679/33732). Also [Printing from TWebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15702976/33732).

Comment: I would use only one of them. The interest is printing, but with changing the view from Grid to HTML I would get more control on the report display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either

- [TWebBrowser printing abilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702976),
- Or a pure VCL component like [THtmlViewer](https://github.com/BerndGabriel/HtmlViewer).

I like very much `THtmlViewer` since it won't depend on the IE installation, is pretty fast and has good printing abilities. You can even export to pdf if needed, using e.g. [Open Source SynPdf unit](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=56).

Comment: This THTMLViewer looks nice but uses HTML files. Can I view a string with HTML content?

Comment: THTMLViewer has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/BerndGabriel/HtmlViewer and SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlviewer/